# Можно ли очищать полученные значения события onMessage() библиотеки WebSocket-Sharp?

Tags: c#, websocket

Требуется написать небольшой клиент на c#, который мог бы взаимодействовать со сторонним сервисом по протоколу WebSocket. Для реализации данной задачи, использую https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp.

Вся суть задачи заключается в том, что нужно вызвать определенные методы сервиса, и обработать полученные результаты. Для обработки возвращаемого результата метода, использую следующий код:

```
websocket.onMessage += (sender, e) => 
Console.WriteLine("Service response: " + e.Data);
```

Методы вызываю по очереди: `method1()`, `method2()` и `method3()`. Каждый из них возвращает определенный ответ из сервиса. Тут то и возникает проблема, а точнее, дублируются полученные ответы данных методов. Другими словами, в консоль результаты выполнения методов выводятся по несколько раз. Примерно так:

`result1 \n result2 \n result2 \n result3 \n result3 \n result3`

`connect()` вызываю только один раз.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Может как-то можно очищать значения полученные onMessage?

Comment: Все таки было бы недурственно взглянуть на код, в котором вы запрашиваете соединение и пытаетесь получить ответ, а не эту фигню: `Console.WriteLine("Service response: " + e.Data);`

Comment: Bulson, пришлось по-другому перефразировать свой вопрос в новой теме.  Вот ссылка на новую ветку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740716/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-onmessage-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA