# Как заполнить коллекцию внутри события OnMessage(), и вернуть ее в главный поток ?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, websocket, события

Доброго времени суток всем!

Пишу небольшой websocket client для взаимодействия с веб-сервисом. Для этого подключаю стороннюю библиотеку [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp).

Если упростить, то задача клиента состоит в том, чтобы вызвать определенные методы сервиса и обработать их. Как известно, при возвращении методом значения, срабатывает событие OnMessage() сокета. То есть таким образом, можно отлавливать все возвращаемые результаты методов данного веб-сервиса.

В моем случае, я помещал полученные значения в ArrayList, для дальнейшего его использования. Лист заполнялся значениями, но при его использовании, в том же методе main(), он всегда оказывался пустым. Как будто никакого заполнения и не происходило.

Вот как я это делаю в коде:

```
class Service
{
    static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ws = new WebSocket(WSSpathToService))
        {
            ws.Connect();

            ws.Send(someJsonCommandToService);

            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //заполняем коллекцию.
                list.Add(e.Data);
                //Тут размер list > 0
            };

            //вот тут list уже пустой
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            ws.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Как выяснилось позже, добавление значении в коллекцию в событие OnMessage() и выборка данной коллекции происходят в разных потоках. Отсюда вопрос, как в консольном приложении правильно заполнить коллекцию значениями, полученными в рамках события onMessage(), и передать его в главный поток, для дальнейшего использования ?

Comment: А вы уверены, что перечисление вашего списка происходит после вызова обработчика вашего сообщения?

Comment: `//вот тут list уже пустой` — тут он не _уже_ пустой, а _ещё_ пустой.

Comment: Хм, да точно, вы правы, перед самой выборкой лист может быть еще пустым. Подскажите пожалуйста, как тогда разрешить этот вопрос.

Comment: очевидно, вам нужно блокировать основной поток до тех пор, пока таймаут не выйдет или пока сообщение не приедет. Для этого воспользуйтесь инструментами синхронизации потоков (я бы пригляделся к ```AutoResetEvent```). Ну и, как совет, сначала подписывайтесь на события и только потом отправляйте запросы на сервер, чтобы не вышло так, что ваше событие прилетело бы к вам до подписки.

Comment: Забавно, что в самой документации показан пример правильной работы: сначала подписаться на событие, а затем уже создавать коннект и отсылать сообщение. У вас же все наоборот. Почему?

Comment: tym32167, благодарю за наводку. Так и сделал, дождался пока прилетят все сообщения, а уже потом работал с ними. Правда AutoResetEvent не использовал, обошелся только этим:
  'while (list.Count < 3)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("waiting for the filling list...");
                }'

Comment: Bulson, да вы правы, исправил этот момент. Видать во время проб различных вариантов, ошибся на этом месте. Спасибо.

Comment: @ismdmr Имейте ввиду, что ```List<T>``` не является потокобезопасным,  он не предназначен для работы с ним из разных потоков, потому существует (хоть и небольшая) вероятность, что ваш код отвалится при одновременном изменении листа и проверки количества в нем элементов. Вместо листа вы можете использовать [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, исправил.